# Properly restore photos to Lumia 1020

Tags: 8.1, photos, backup, camera, nokia-lumia-1020

I have just reinstalled the firmware on my Lumia 1020 in order to get Cyan (I was on 8.1 Dev Prev) and am now busy restoring everything.

I had about 7GBs worth of photos on it, all of which is now on OneDrive. Downloading 7GB will take me days though so I made an offline copy of the entire Pictures directory on my PC. Everything seems to have copied nicely to my PC with date EXIF info etc.

My problem now is that simply copying this folder back does not seem to work properly as all the info like dates are then lost once they reach the phone, this means that my photos are now not properly organized and I cannot open high res images with Nokia Camera anymore.

Is there any way that I can copy the images back to my phone properly without having to download them from OneDrive?

PS. My PC is running Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Now that you have Cyan installed, did you go back on the Dev Preview programme to get 8.1 Update 1?

Comment: @NeilTurner but of course...

Comment: Ok, when you updated to 8.1 Update 1, did you reset and restore from that backup?

Comment: @NeilTurner it asked me to restore before going to update 1 so it restored before that. Everything except my photos was restored though.

Comment: Then it won't restore properly. If your current version is 8.1 Update 1, you can only restore to *that* version properly. Restoring to an earlier version means Start Menu + app data doesn't get restored properly.

Comment: @NeilTurner ok, that might be true and I have noticed that but it is not as if I could have afforded to restore my images over the internet in the first place. I am trying to figure out how can do this from of the backup on my PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16832/discussion-between-neil-turner-and-gerhman).

Comment: Check this link, it should be easy as you wanted.. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/product/lumia1020/userguidance/?action=singleTopic&topic=B-GUID-82B2F70B-597F-4EA1-9018-67658DC3E24A

Answer (score 1):

go into nokia camera > settings, scroll to the bottom and click find photos and videos. That should associate your files back to the nokia camera app